# Javacc Regular expression to match particular type of string?

Tags: regex, javacc

I am trying to write the regular expression for the token, so that if the string is passed **" 123 " ' "** then the string should be **123 " '**
Since my current regex is

```
<T_STRING:

        "\"" (~["\""]|"^\"")* "\""
        | "'"(~["'"]|"^'" )* "'"

    >
```

I am not able to get the output like 123  " '. Instead it only detect first part "123" rest of them **' "** are ignored .

Question is how can I write the regex for the token so that it can give me desired output.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me why you consider `"123"'"` to be a string. Do you have a grammar of what you consider a string?

Comment: I'm unfarmiliar with the regex syntax you are using, but just enclose your regex and add dot meta to get the rest of the string. `(?: your regex ).*`

Comment: How about `" 123 \"'"`?  Not what you are looking for?

Can you explain the syntax of strings for your language in plain English or give us a pointer to a reference manual?

Comment: @nhahtdh think this way if I am implementing command prompt, I am trying to execute the command . In this situation there is regular expression which tells whatever content in between " " & '' is string .. in this situation if I pass 123 " '   between " " then it will definitely  will fail, because it will pick up "123" and will ignore last 2 character ' "....so because of that I was looking for regular expression which I found ie. ^\".*\"$  but don't know how to put that in regular expression grammer that lexical analyzer will use

Comment: By `$` do you mean the end of the file?  The end of the line?  What should your lexer do if the last character is not a `"`?

Comment: "$ means look for last " in the string. ..so if the string is " 123 ' " " " than the string will 123 ' " "